# Java Floats formatting

Tags: java, number-formatting

There is e.x `2.52549856E8` float number.

What I want is simply make it `25.2549856E8`, that's it, everything else can stay.

I sought for solution and all I found was with bunch of string examples.

I get pure float number. Should I convert it to String first? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Have you poked around the Java trails: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html ... this question has been asked _many_ times before on this site.

Comment: `2.52549856E8 * 10 = 25.2549856E7` this is just a simple calculation, isn't it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Problem is, I can't use those functions because I'm using floats and printing to console with append already, to use those functions I have to re-write a lot of stuff.

Comment: @lino it doesn't work that way, precision is required and it still doesn't print me as I want.

Comment: Then how do you want it, i can't see a way to come from `2.52549856E8` to `25.2549856E8`. Do you just want to place the dot one digit to the right or what?

Comment: @Lino yes, thats what I want. In C language it's simple, but java somehow it's more difficult.

Comment: @Gaxt see the answer below, that should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to just move the dot one digit to the right, you can use following snippet, which uses `String#substring()` to cut the `String` into the right parts and then concatenates them again:

```
String number = String.valueOf(2.52549856E8f);
int index = number.indexOf('.');
String formatted = 
    number.substring(0, index) + 
    number.substring(index + 1, index + 2) + 
    '.' + 
    number.substring(index + 2);
```

1. `number.substring(0, index)` cuts the first digit out
2. `number.substring(index + 1, index + 2)` cuts the second digit out
3. `'.'` inserts the new dot
4. `number.substring(index + 2)` appends the rest of the number

The same can be done with regex:

```
String number = String.valueOf(2.52549856E8f);
String formatted = number.replaceAll("^(\\d)\\.(\\d)(\\d+E\\d+)$", "$1$2.$3");
```

Comment: @Gaxt You're welcome. I guess that's probably the only way there currently is.